# R difference between expression and as.expression

Tags: r

Well, here's what I do:

```
D(expression(x^2),"x")
# 2 * x
D(as.expression(x^2),"x")
# [1] 0
class(as.expression(x^2))
# [1] "expression"
class(expression(x^2))
# [1] "expression"
```

So, why the different result? I guess R handles those things slightly differently, and I want to understand how exactly. A manual on R where such nuances are covered, if you know one, is also very welcome.

Comment: I get an error with `D(as.expression(x^2),"x")`. Did you define any `x` in your workspace?

Comment: And I would suggest to read the help, if not already done.

Comment: Yes, x was in global envir, sorry. 'x=2' gives '[1] 0'. I did read the help for D(), checked '?as.expression' and it says that it works as 'as.vector(type=expression)' in default which is probably the cause of difference in behavior but I don't understand the underlying mechanics and I want to. I have feeling that help in R is a reference for those who understands rather than guide to those who learn (and it probably should be) that's why seek a good manual.

Comment: `expression` returns an object of R's type "expression" which is a "list" of unevaluated objects of type "symbol". `as.expression` evaluates and coerces its argument (if possible) to a type "expression". Perhaps see, also, the difference in behavior in making and coercing of a very similar R type - "list": `list(1, 2)` and `as.list(1, 2)` and, also, `expression(substitute(xxx))` vs `as.expression(substitute(xxx))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have defined `x` as number in the global environment, when you use `as.expression(x^2)` the function will try to convert the content of `x` and not its name to an expression.

See:

```
x = 1
as.expression(x^2)
# expression(1)
```

So when you run `D(as.expression(x^2), "x")` you are actually running `D(expression(1), "x")` which is zero.